# Need to use WLAN in android

Tags: android

I developed an app for android tablet, Now i need to perform certain actions on the app through my android phone using WLAN... How to do it?

Comment: can you describe the "certain actions"?

Comment: Like to lock my application through my android mobile...

Comment: WLAN would be a gud option becoz of its range.Initially i thought of using Bluetooth but since range of bluetooth is less, so i dropped the idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app can create a server socket to receive client requests, and then interpret commands that your remote client sends to it. [This page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) might help you with the Android server socket part of things.